# advice about ASP.NET and PHP for building an auction web site

Tags: php, asp.net

I need expert advises about building an auction web site in general and I dont need code help.

I stopped one year for developing web sites and I need to know which is more suitable and easy to extend to build this web site

If I used ASP.NET which ORM I should use or I dont have to use it ? and should I use expression web as the IDE ?

I know also there is some good PHP frameworks like CodeIgniter, CakePHP ,etc... but which one is the best for all development cycle ? or should I use Joomla and just build plugins ?

Which JS framework also is more suitable for build fast and cool UI ?

I learn fast so dont worry about the learning problems **I just need expert advises about what I should use today to enforce the rules for building clean , standard and cool modern web site.**

Thanks alot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always, it depends. Having worked with both (a lot in PHP, dabbled in ASP.NET) Generally speaking, I'd say that .Net offers cleaner code, while PHP offers faster code (as in developer-time). In my experience, ASP.Net offers cleaner code due to the framework being built-in, whereas PHP offers more freedom right off the bat.

With the new ASP.Net MVC extension, I'd definitely recommend using it for any newly-built large  application, whereas about two years ago I'd still have enthousiastically said PHP.

Building a "fast and cool UI" doesn't depend very much on the JS framework you choose - most frameworks offer everything you need to do this. It depends more on what the developer is most comfortable with. Generally, I'd say Sencha (formerly known as Ext JS) or Dojo would be a good bet.

Comment: ok if possible can you give me a hint why MVC ?
and for tools: Microsoft Visual Studio and what else ?
for UI I al looking for fast and clean build , how about devexpress controls ?

I remember this site http://www.condo.com and I like alot the design.

thanks alot

Comment: MVC offers you the freedom to determine how the pages render - for modern web applications, this is a major benefit. Of course, it IS possible to do this with classic Webforms, but it's a lot harder. MVC lends itself very well for modern AJAX-inspired interfaces.

Tools: If you go with .Net, I'd say Visual Studio and Web Expression. Don't need much beside those :)

Comment: many thanks

I use expression web for CSS, layout design and VS for coding ?

Comment: upvote on this answer, although I would say for a JS framework go with jQuery.  it's pretty ubiquitous now and offers plugins for just about anything you'd want to do.  plus lots of great help on SO if you get stuck. :)

Comment: any one know how to use telerik ajax controls with mvc ? (I asked this before but did not get a good replay)

thanks